# AWS SageMaker Real-Time inference configure storage size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sagemaker

i'm currently using SageMaker real-time inference (and async inference) since September.

Now my endpoint workload increased such that i need to process a couple hundreds of HD photos (each about 30-40 MB) and after the processing i want to create a zip with the processed photos and upload back to S3.

Everything works fine till i'm under 80/90 photos, because after that, during zipping part, i get from Sagemaker endpoint (Cloudwatch log):

> OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

I think "No problem, i can simply increase the storage option in the hosting of the Sagemaker endpoint", but in reality there is not such option nor in "Models", "Endpoint configuration" or "Endpoint".

I'm using **ML.M4.XLARGE** machine.

My questions are:

1. *Is it possible increase Storage size on Sagemaker Async/Real-time endpoint?*
2. *Which is the default Storage configuration on Sagemaker Async/Real-time endpoints?*

Thank you